# How can I turn this click event function into one that is called automatically when the div loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, dynamic

I perform a function which loads content into a div. I am using innerHTML, I GET a php file, which updates the innerHTML of the div with the php file's content.

This div contains another div inside it with the class and id of "tweet". This div is updated with actual tweets of a specific hashtag, passed to the function through a $variable

It works fine when it is simply an onclick event, such as this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="tweet('<?echo $hashtag;?>')">activity</a></p>
<div class="tweet" id="tweet"></div>
```

However, what I want to do is have it automatically load tweet('') once the "tweet" div has loaded.

The tweet(hashtag) function is:

```
function tweet(hashtag) { $("#tweet").load('tweet.php?hashtag='+hashtag); }
```

which loads a php file that calls the jquery tweet function.

```
 jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
        avatar_size: 32,
        count: 3,
        query: "<?echo $hashtag;?>",
        loading_text: "loading tweets...",
        refresh_interval: 3
    });
});
```

Based on the hashtag passed, it shows 3 tweets.
The hashtag is called when the page is loaded, as a session variable.

It all works fine when I click the link.  What do I need to do to have this load automatically. so that I don't need to click the link?  I have tried a number of autorefresh options but couldn't quite get it.  I would really appreciate assistance.

I know that, if this was just a regular page being loaded, I can simply use $(document).ready and call the jquery function.  However, due to the way the div is populated with the new php file contents, it doesn't work. I have tried a few times using autorefresh intervals, window onload, etc. They don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to try this:

1. Run the code somehow from the function which you call to load the div.  (Guaranteed to work.  You may even put together some kind of plugin concept.  "eval" may be useful.)
2. Add a  tag after the div.  If things work as you hope, that code will execute immediately.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The function works. If I click the word "activity", it will load 3 tweets into the div "tweet" below it.

However, I don't want to have to click the link, I want it to just perform the function on its own.

Comment: @DonShappelle:  If you are in charge of the page which loads the div, you can run code then.  So fill the div, then call the method.

Comment: The initial click calls a function that updates the innerHTML of the left div with a php file.  Another function is called to update the contents of the right div with a php file. (innerhtml = http response which is a GET of a php file). The hashtag is grabbed when the left div innerhtml is updated via the GET.  The right side can pull the session value and output it, but that's where it ends. I feel like I'd need to rework the initial javascript calls in order to get this to work automatically.  If you are free to chat at donshappelle.com/chat I'd appreciate 5 minutes of your time.

Comment: I edited the initial function to include the tweet() function after loading both sides of the page. The timing was a bit off but I adjusted the order and now it processes nicely. Left side loads, right side loads, tweets load within right side. Takes about .002 seconds. Thanks!